# How do I specifiy the order of parameters when doing HTTPGET?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

How do you specify the order in which parameters should be appended to the url when using HttpPost?

At the moment Im using :

```
def httpPost(url,resource,params):
     headers = {
            "Content-type" : "application/json",
     }
     conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url, timeout=10)
     temp_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
     conn.request("POST", resource, temp_params, headers)
     response = conn.getresponse()
     data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
     params.clear()
     conn.close()
     return data
```

similar to the httpGet example code from https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html which both accepts, for the params parameter, a {} type input which i can't create an order on.

```
>>> params= {'search': 'qwert','bolt': 'asdf'} # arbitrary order 
>>> print(params)
{'bolt': 'asdf', 'search': 'qwert'}  #out of order
```

Since Im using a site's API I need the keys=values to be in a certain order. Is there a way to modify the code to accept a list instead?

Maybe something that accepts:

```
['key=xxx-yyy-zzz-111-333', 'nonce=2487236483724', 'pageIndex=1', 'pageSize=10']
```

where each element keeps their position in the list.

Comment: Try an ordered dictionary? `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: `urllib.parse.urlencode` should already take a list as input.